# Dithering (Images) - How Exactly Does It Work?

Tags: image-processing, dithering

Am I correct in thinking that dithering an image works in the following way:

I have a 2x2 image block consisting of individual pixels (x):

```
x  |  x
¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
x  |  x
```

I wish to dither the image via the following values:

```
3  |  4
¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
2  |  1
```

Therefore, will the 2x2 block appear as:

```
x x | x x
x   | x x
¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
x x | x 
    |
```

Is this correct?  If so, have I illustrated the dithered pixel layouts correctly?

Or am I completely mistaken?  If so, could somebody kindly enlighten me (ideally with an example)?

I am aware that the sample size that I chose to use is a small one, but it was merely for illustration purposes.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this is the correct method.

Comment: How did you reach this conclusion? Thanks.

Comment: Seeing as I provided this answer approximately three-and-a-half years ago, I cannot remember the specifics but what I do remember is that I consulted with a PhD friend of mine who confirmed that this is correct.